# How mysql clear the html tags?

Tags: mysql, sql, string

How can I retrieve just text (no html tags) from a table?

example:

```
<P align=center>
 <FONT color=red size=3>OP can't figure out this is inappropriate</FONT>
</P>
```

I want get:

> OP can't figure out this is inappropriate

Using SQL.

Comment: Which server-side script are you using for fetching data from mysql database?

Comment: Just like "<img src=""/>some infomation" ect

Comment: PHP and perl,but I know strip_tags。

Comment: No, MySQL (nor other databases to my knowledge) have functions for specifically removing HTML/etc markup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't have HTML markup in your database.  Are you saying that it has markup now, and you'd like to be rid of it?

I'd change the app to not add HTML markup so you don't get any more.

Then I'd do a one-shot modification to remove the markup and persist only the text that I wanted.

Your question is quite vague.  You might have better luck getting an answer if you edit it and add more detail.  What do you want to do?

Comment: I just want to know if Mysql have some function to fo with this?

Comment: There is one specific case where that is the preferred option - specifically when you need to store a bunch of text formatted by the user, such as a content management system. You do however have to implement proper security in order to prevent sql injection attacks. But this specific case it pretty much the only way to go about it it, if you want to let users use any WYSIWYG editor.